# xCode can't find header files in Unity3D project

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I'm building an iOS app using unity3D. Everything goes ok until I try to build the solution. Unity builds the xCode project with 0 problems but then, when I try to build with xCode, I get several, all of them the same: "*.h not found".

The problem in this is that the headers don't exist in the project folder, but in the original-unity project folder they do exist.

I've seen a lot of similar problems around the web, but most of them relate to independent xCode projects, being the solution messing with the paths and so on... But with a project built by unity is it supposed to change that? When I go check them, they seem correct...

I've also seen that unity had a problem and by reinstalling it would fix the problem. Unfortunately it didn't...

Does anyone know what kind of problem is this? Should I change the build paths even though unity set them some way? Is it unity's fault?

Thank in advance

Comment: Ok, I've managed to work things through, though I'm not sure this is the best thing to do... I just included the original-unity-project folder to the header path. Still, the question remains: shouldn't that be unity's work?

Comment: Do you mean own header files from native code plugins or the Unity generated stuff like iPhone_Common.h?

Comment: header files from native code plugins

Comment: what about iPhone_Common.h   I have that problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native plugins need to be stored in special folder Plugins, for iOS it is Assets/Plugins/iOS. Citing from [Unity - Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html):

Automated plugin integration

*Unity iOS supports automated plugin integration in a limited way. All files with extensions .a,.m,.mm,.c,.cpp located in the Assets/Plugins/iOS folder will be merged into the generated Xcode project automatically. However, merging is done by symlinking files from Assets/Plugins/iOS to the final destination, which might affect some workflows. The .h files are not included in the Xcode project tree, but they appear on the destination file system, thus allowing compilation of .m/.mm/.c/.cpp files.

Note: **subfolders are currently not supported**.*

I marked the subfolders statement bold as I ran into trouble with this some time ago :)

Comment: Thank you very much! this is the answer I needed to hear! Thanks